# Xcode generic project indexing

Tags: xcode, indexing

I'm new to Xcode and I can't get some basic indexing working.

I'm trying to use it as an editor for project with custom build system and is not supposed to be built on Mac OS at all. So I'm trying to use Xcode more as advanced source code editor, rather then as full featured IDE.

The problem is that it won't build any kind of index, so staff like "go to definition" won't work.

On the other hand sublime and eclipse would provide me with at least some indexing, which was not ideal, but it still worked.

UPDATE: in terms of languages used there's nothing hardcore or ecstatic. 90% of the project is plain C.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I would have thought the languages that Xcode understands is pretty hardcoded, so I don't think there is much you can do about it.

Comment: Updated the question. Language is C and I guess, it's supposed to be understood by Xcode.

Comment: Ah OK, then I would expect that only to work if you are editing an Xcode project that creates an executable/library.  You might want to look at using cmake to generate your Xcode prioject/Makefile/whatever as a way of abstracting the project and allowing you to use whatever editor you like.  It's very good indeed.